# Select TOP N and set variable if more could be selected

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a more efficient way of doing the following SQL?

I want to select the top 50 results, but I also want to set a variable to tell me if I would have gotten more results back without the TOP

```
DECLARE @MoreExists BIT
SET @MoreExists = 0

DECLARE @Count INT
SELECT @Count = Count(*) 
   FROM MyTable WHERE ... --some expensive where clause

IF @Count > 50
    SET @MoreExists = 1

SELECT TOP 50 Field1, Field2, ... 
    FROM MyTable WHERE ... --same expensive where clause
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select 51 results instead, use the top 50 in the client layer, and use the count to know if there are more.

Comment: hm.. that is the obvious and simplest way of doing it. Pass my Stored Proc the count that I'm expected, and then in the SP increase that number by one, and in the code check if the count returned is greater than I asked for.

Answer (score 2):

A spin on @Dougs answer

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 

SELECT TOP 51 Field1, Field2, ... 
    into #t
    FROM MyTable WHERE ... --same expensive where clause

if @@rowcount > 50 
      SET @MoreExists = 1

 SET NOCOUNT OFF

 SELECT TOP 50 Field1, Field2, ... 
    from #t
    -- maintain ordering with an order by clause
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The common approach is to use ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH MyTableEntries AS 
( 
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Row, col1, col2 
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE
          -- some expensive WHERE clause
)
SELECT col1, col2
FROM MyTableEntries 
WHERE Row BETWEEN(@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and @PageIndex*@PageSize
```

The efficient approach shown at this [SqlServercentral article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/):

```
DECLARE @startRow INT ; SET @startrow = 50
;WITH cols
AS
(
    SELECT table_name, column_name, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name, column_name) AS seq, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY table_name DESC, column_name desc) AS totrows
    FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].columns
)
SELECT table_name, column_name, totrows + seq -1 as TotRows
FROM cols
WHERE seq BETWEEN @startRow AND @startRow + 49
ORDERBY seq
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using COUNT(*) OVER... in a sub-query?

```
DECLARE @ReqCount int;
SET @ReqCount = 50;

SELECT TOP (@ReqCount) *
FROM 
(
SELECT *, Count(*) OVER() AS TotalCnt
FROM MyTable WHERE ...
) t
ORDER BY ...
;
```

And if you want to use ROW_NUMBER() too, then try:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ...) AS RowNum, Count(*) OVER() AS TotalCnt
FROM MyTable WHERE ...
) t
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN @StartRange AND @EndRange
ORDER BY ...
;
```

And then you can easily check to see if TotalCnt > @ReqCount (or @EndRange), to be able to see if there are more to fetch.

Rob